# ObserveOn with Scheduler.NewThread does not observe so, if observer's OnNext is blocked and continued

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

Can some one please help explain why when I "block and continue" observer's onNext sequence subscribed to a buffer with time observable sequence, that Scheduler.NewThread does not apply anymore?

For example:

If I buffer a sequence of number via

```
var query = from number in Enumerable.Range(1,200)
            select SnoozeNumberProduction(number);

var observableQuery = query.ToObservable();
var bufferedSequence = observableQuery.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

Where SnoozeNumberProduction delays the number generation by 250 ms

```
static int SnoozeNumberProduction(Int32 number)
{
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    return number;
}
```

Now later if i subscribe to the bufferedSequence with an "ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread)" such that I block on the fourth buffer with a Console.ReadKey

```
Random random = new Random();
Int32 count = 0;
bufferedSequence.ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(list =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("({0}) Numbers from {1}-{2} produced on Thread ID {3}", list.Count, list[0], list[list.Count -1], Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    count++;
    if (count == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("count reached to 4, blocking ... press any key to continue ");
        Console.ReadKey(); // Block and build up the queue
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Woken " + list[0] + " - " + list[list.Count - 1]);
});
```

In this case if I hit any key after say 10 seconds or so, I see that the following next few buffers execute on the same ManagedThread even when Scheduler.NewThread is mentioned in the ObserveOn. Can someone please help explain this behavior?

Sample output:

```
(7) Numbers from 1-7 produced on Thread ID 12
Woken 1 - 7
(9) Numbers from 8-16 produced on Thread ID 14
Woken 8 - 16
(8) Numbers from 17-24 produced on Thread ID 15
Woken 17 - 24
(8) Numbers from 25-32 produced on Thread ID 16
count reached to 4, blocking ... press any key to continue
Woken 25 - 32
(8) Numbers from 33-40 produced on Thread ID **16**
Woken 33 - 40
(8) Numbers from 41-48 produced on Thread ID **16**
Woken 41 - 48
(8) Numbers from 49-56 produced on Thread ID **16**
Woken 49 - 56
(8) Numbers from 57-64 produced on Thread ID **16**
Woken 57 - 64
(8) Numbers from 65-72 produced on Thread ID **16**
Woken 65 - 72
(8) Numbers from 73-80 produced on Thread ID **16**
Woken 73 - 80
(8) Numbers from 81-88 produced on Thread ID **16**
Woken 81 - 88
(8) Numbers from 89-96 produced on Thread ID **16**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted this question to MSDN Rx forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/52e72a11-9841-4571-b86d-f805d3aeb7b5 and learnt that this is for efficiency reasons

---

You're blocking the call to OnNext in Subscribe.
**The ObserveOn operator ensures that OnNext will be called as many times as possible on the current thread.**
The ObserveOn operator reuses the current thread to call OnNext, sequentially, for as many values as are currently available.  **Since you're blocking in Subscribe, multiple calls to OnNext will accumulate.  After you unblock, the queued calls are executed on the same thread.  I believe this is to avoid the overhead of creating a new thread per notification when it's unnecessary.**

Answer (score 2):

`ObserveOn` is itself a layer in your composed sequence that's only job is to swap to another scheduler. However, your sleeps are happening in a `Select` occuring on an `IEnumerable`. That sequence is then being converted to an `IObservable` using `ToObservable`, which defaults to `Dispatcher.CurrentThread`.

It's only at this point that you are swapping to another thread for each item that comes in. If you change it to:

```
var query = from number in Enumerable.Range(1,200).ToObservable(Dispatcher.NewThread)
            select SnoozeNumberProduction(number);

var bufferedSequence = query.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

Now the *enumeration* occurs on a new thread and, as you're not doing anything to change that, it will stay there.

There's actually an `Observable.Range` that starts as an `IObservable` and takes an optional `IDispatcher`. However, I assumed your source is not actually `Enumerable.Range`. In case it is, here's the equivalent:

```
var query = from number in Observable.Range(1,200, Dispatcher.NewThread)
            select SnoozeNumberProduction(number);

var bufferedSequence = query.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```